# how can i kick off a process when a linux system boots up?

Tags: linux, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add an application to run as a service in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/115438/how-to-add-an-application-to-run-as-a-service-in-linux)

is there a script in /etc i should edit?  What is recommended. Right now im running something in .profile but that's kind of not what i want.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `cron`.  Most Linux machines will use Vixie cron, which has the meta time spec `@reboot`.

See http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab and look for @reboot

Much easier than setting up stuff in /etc/, especially if you want it to run as you and not root.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add it to your /etc/rc.local on Ubuntu.  Varies on other distros but should be similar.

```
find /etc -name \*local\* -print
```

Comment: Just in case: on Gentoo, `/etc/conf.d/local.start` to start a program and `/etc/conf.d/local.stop` to stop it (if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

/etc/rc.local

[This site](http://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8116-an-introduction-to-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts) says: "This script file is run once, before all other scripts have run but before the logon prompt appears."

If its a gui app you want launched then its probably specific to your desktop enviroment. Gnome under ubuntu has a "startup applications" tool under system/preferences