# How can I run a command after boot?

Tags: linux, boot, script, init, systemd

I would like to run the simple shell command `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` at each boot, to enable the sysrq keys. When in boot should this be done, and where should I put a script to do it?

Comment: All Linux distributions already sets the time. Maybe the battery to your RTC on the motherboard is low?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg actually there is no RTC on my motherboard :) It's a embedded system board without RTC.

Comment: Also http://superuser.com/questions/183921/how-can-i-kick-off-a-process-when-a-linux-system-boots-up

Comment: I beg to differ, @davidgo. The references you are quoting are a tad obsolete: while crontab does work, /etc/rc.local does not on `systemd` distros like Arch Linux. By referring to them, we might be sending Demetri on a wild goose chase. Some updating, at times, needs to be done.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Depends on distros.

If you are on Debian-derived distros, there are at least two proper places, /etc/rc.local and crontab. You may invoke crontab as root,

```
   crontab -e
```

and then insert this line

```
   @reboot /home/my_name/bin/my_command
```

where `my_command` is an executable file (`chmod 755 my_command`).

Alternatively, you may place a line like this

```
   /home/my_name/bin/my_command
```

in /etc/rc.local, and this will be executed last. In any case, pls do remember you are using root environment, not yours. Also for this reason, it is best to use absolute paths.

If you are on a **systemd** distro (Arch Linux, Fedora 19,...) the first option (crontab) is still valid, while the second one (/etc/rc.local) does not exist any longer. In this case, you should learn how to start a service to be run by `systemctl`, but this may be more than you bargained for with your simple question.

Comment: Can you confirm this for Fedora ?  My searching tells me that rc.local will still run if it exists and is executable, but is not set up by default.  I perceived troubling ramifications if rc.local does not run !  (I could only find references for this for Fedora 18 - http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=291889)

Comment: You are right, in Fedora 19 you might still have it, if you really want it. But it is no longer packaged, http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/Release_Notes/sect-Release_Notes-Changes_for_Sysadmin.html bullet 3.2.4. Also, it does not exist in Arch Linux altogether, so I thought it safe to include a warning about that.

Comment: maybe this is an unknown alias for me but `@boot` does not exist, just  `@reboot` http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/crontab.htm

Comment: This has never ever worked for me with any Debian distro

Answer (score 20):

If your system is running a version of `cron` that supports it (specifically Vixie cron), you can use `@reboot` in a cron job.

This is one of 8 special strings that it supports.

Quoting the `crontab(5)` man page (from my Ubuntu 12.04 system):

> Instead of the first five fields, one of eight special strings may appear:

```
string         meaning
------         -------
@reboot        Run once, at startup.
@yearly        Run once a year, "0 0 1 1 *".
@annually      (same as @yearly)
@monthly       Run once a month, "0 0 1 * *".
@weekly        Run once a week, "0 0 * * 0".
@daily         Run once a day, "0 0 * * *".
@midnight      (same as @daily)
@hourly        Run once an hour, "0 * * * *".
```

> Please  note  that startup, as far as `@reboot` is concerned, is the time when the *cron(8)* daemon startup.  In particular, it may be before  some system  daemons, or other facilities, were startup.  This is due to the boot order sequence of the machine.

This is far from being the *only* way to run something at boot time, but it's an alternative.

Comment: How can this answer have been written **more than a year before** the original question?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294543/827263

Comment: +1 for specifying that requires Vixie cron.

Answer (score 10):

Pretty much all variants of Linux (going back a long, long time) have a file /etc/rc.local which runs on startup - you can just add the command to it.

That said, you don't even need to do that.  The "correct" way would be to modify / add the line kernel.sysrq = 1 into /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: I almost got what you said but I'm stuck with your last sentence: The "correct" way would be to modify / add the line kernel.sysrq = 1 into /etc/sysctl.conf (you stopped here) ... do you have extra explanation here? then how can I run the extra command after putting `kernel.sysrq=1`

Comment: @KalibZen You can type "sysctl -p" to get sysctl to reload the settings from /etc/sysctl.conf.

Comment: No, not that one, the question is about startup.. The first paragraph I got it you talk about /etc/rc.local but the last paragraph I don't understand what are you trying to say. What is the kernel.sysrq =1 has to do with startup ?

Comment: Ok, now I got it, the last paragraph is not about startup as mentioned by OP but you gave solution how to overcome that without using startup method. Forgive me to just read the title question not the content of the question. But if you could rephrase your last paragraph to explicitly say, 'for your case' then it's going to be clear. I mistakenly read the last paragraph as 'you don't even need to do that; meaning I misunderstood not to do the rc.local thing and you came out with the kernel.sysrq=1 thing)

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. (The OS automatically reads sysctl.conf  and actions this on startup)